# Monitor randomly turns off when I do something in fullscreen

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I'm using Arch Linux. Here's the problem -- when I do something in fullscreen (e.g. watching a video, or playing a game) my monitor randomly turns off for a second or so and turns on again. There are no logs after this, according to gnome-logs.  This issue appears in GNOME Xorg, GNOME Wayland, Cinnamon Xorg. In Windows 10 everything works fine.

All drivers are installed and up to date.
[image]

Comment: When I watch a video or playing a game in windowed mode, everything works fine

Comment: Since it works in Windows, this must be a driver problem. Try to find a better driver. I have found [this page](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-prorad-lin-18-40), but don't know if it will work for Arch.

Comment: Maybe try another monitor. It could be that, while switching the modes, the monitor gets no signal for a (very) short time. Some monitors then then try to search a signal on their other inputs = therefore appear as if they are turned off. Or try fixing the input at the monitor. In Windows, when you switch to fullscreen, the monitor mode is no longer changed.

Comment: @harrymc AMDGPU-PRO is very outdated on Arch. I tried to patch it by myself but without any success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by adding a bootflag

```
amdgpu.dc=0
```